# How to create legend in jQuery as in Geo chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, I need a legend with multiple colors as marked in below Geo chart.
[image]

Can anyone please give some guidance to do this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use css to render like this [`example`](http://jsfiddle.net/yvgYV/76/)